# links colours are not changing

Tags: css

I have a problem with my links colors. That is I have given these css properties:

```
#profiletabs ul li a:link,a:visited {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 7px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}
#profiletabs ul li a:hover,a:active {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #5dcb03,#65de03);
background-color: #5dcb03;
}


#tablist li .activelink {
 color: #5dcb03;
background: #f5f5f5;
border-top: 1px solid #028ec6;
}
#tablist li .activelink:hover
{
background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

this should be look like this:

[image]

but it is looking like this:

[image]

I am changing the color of the links by using jQuery. It is running on my laptop perfectly   but on running live this problem is happening.

Please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `.` css option you must use the same selector string as the first  so

```
#profiletabs ul li a:link, #profiletabs ul li a:linka:visited {
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
padding: 7px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}
#profiletabs ul li a:hover, #profiletabs ul li a:active {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #5dcb03,#65de03);
background-color: #5dcb03;
}
```

and so on

Comment: OP should feel lucky you answered!  Those links to a advertising hole were enough to make me run away from this!